# When to use a Property as opposed to a Label in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am going over this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh_79goBRUk), "Using LOAD CSV in the Real World".

The tutorial shows how to take a CSV, where each row is a complaint made against some bank, and model it as a Neo4j dictionary.

When doing so, the narrator sets Properties on the Complaint node:

```
CREATE (complaint:Complaint {id: line.`Complaint ID`})
SET complaint.year= TOINT(date[2]),
     complaint.month= TOINT(date[0]),
     complaint.day = TOINT(date[1])
```

I'm confused about a small point -- what makes this date information more of a 'Property' than a Label?

Could this be modeled instead where the node has this information encapsulated as Labels instead of Properties? At what point do you need one of these and not the other?

Comment: http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/01/16/neo4j-graph-model-design-labels-versus-indexed-properties.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels and properties are very different things.

A `property` belongs to a node or a relationship, and has a name and a value.

A node `label` is similar in concept to a "class name", and has no value.

So, it does not make any sense to talk about putting a date value in a "label". You can only put a value in a property.

Note, however, that people often use a label name (e.g., "Foo") as a shorthand for "node that has the `Foo` label". For example, they may say "store the date in Foo" when they actually mean "store the date in the appropriate property of a node with the label Foo". Perhaps this is what is causing the confusion.

Comment: Riding on this comment - just wanted to add, I use a property when I need to store data about a node.  I use labels on when I basically have an enum category that I want indexed for fast query.  If it's not an enum (fixed/small number of options) then it's not a label.  If you don't need it indexed, it's not a label.   Default choice should be property, pick label when you need those two specific things.  Labels let you partition the graph by your chosen enum.

Answer (score 1):

As cybersam pointed out in his answer, labels cannot contain values. They are just... labels. Like a tag. Taking this in a slightly different direction:

A long, long time ago, in a version far, far away, Neo4j didn't have labels. So, if you wanted to identify a particular type of node (say... a `Person`)... you'd likely include a property+value such as `nodeType = 'Person'`. And then you'd include a filter in your queries, such as:

`WHERE node.nodeType = 'Person'`

Labels make such a property type obsolete, and are also indexable. Further, you may have multiple labels on a node (which would require your legacy `nodeType` property to be an array, and not as efficient to search).

So: Labels for tagging/indexing. Properties for holding values.

Answer (score 0):

" Node labels serve as an anchor point for a query. By specifying a label, we are specifying a subset of one or more nodes with which to start a query. Using a label helps to reduce the amount of data that is retrieved." https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/